# Closure of $\{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 \leq 1\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to find closure of the following set $$A = \{(x,y) \mid 0<x^2 -y^2 \leq 1\}$$

MY attempt:

I have drawn the following plot of $A$.

[image]

I have found out two equations are $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 1$. The first of these is a pair of diagonal lines through the origin that make $45$ degree angles with the coordinate axes, and the second is a hyperbola going through $(-1; 0)$ and $(1,0)$ with asymptotes given by the lines $x^2 - y^2 = 0$.

From diagram, I think $\overline{A} = A \cup \{(x,y) \mid |x| = |y|\}$.

But I was thinking for a mathematical proof.

MY Attempt:

First we will prove that $B = A \cup \{(x,y) \mid |x| = |y|\}$ is closed. To prove $B^c$ open, we need to show for each $(x,y) \in B^c$, there always exists a $r>0$ such that $B_d((x,y), r) \subset B^c$. $\textbf{But how to approach?}$

Suppose we have proved that $B$ is closed. Clearly, $B \supset A$, thus $\overline{A} \subset B$.

Now we want to prove $B \subset \overline{A}$. Clearly $A \subset \overline{A}$, so we need to prove only $\{(x,y) \mid |x| = |y|\}$ is contained in $\overline{A}$, and to prove it we just need to show that for each point in $\{(x,y) \mid |x| = |y|\}$ there is a neighborhood which intersects $A$. $\textbf{But how to show it?}$

Is my idea correct? Please help me for the two question where I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: Since every point in $A$ is also in the closure, all you had to do, right from the start, was to show that the points $\{(x,y): |x|=|y|\}$ are in the boundary of $A$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Actually, I have to find out what is $\partial A$ in the next step,...and to find it I supposed to do $\partial A = \overline{A} - Int(A)$. I  calculated what is $Int(A)$, so at this moment I want to calculate $\overline{A}$.

Comment: Do you know that for a continuous map $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, $\{(x,y) \mid f(x,y) \gt a\}$ is open and $\{(x,y) \mid f(x,y) \le a\}$ is closed for any $a \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Actually, I was thinking like ...if we take $f(x,y) = x^2 -y^2$, then $\{(x,y) \mid 0 \leq x^2 -y^2 \leq 1\} = f^{-1} ([0,1])$, hence a closed set...But Munkres did not introduce continuity till now, so I have to do it using formal definition....since it's  a exercise of Munkres.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with this once and for all:

- If $0<x^2-y^2<1$, then $(x,y)$ is an *interior* point
- If $0>x^2-y^2$ or $x^2-y^2>1$, then $(x,y)$ is an *exterior* point
- If $0=x^2-y^2$ or $x^2-y^2=1$, then $(x,y)$ is a *boundary* point

We can show this without resorting to continuity of $(x,y)\mapsto x^2-y^2$ as follows:

Suppose $0<x^2-y^2<1$. Let $\delta=\min\{x^2-y^2,1-(x^2-y^2)\}>0$ and $r=\min\{1,\frac\delta{2(|x|+|y|+1)}\}$. Then for $|x-\xi|<r$ and $|y-\eta|<r$, we have
$$ \begin{align}\left|(x^2-y^2)-(\xi^2-\eta^2)\right|&=\left|(x-\xi)(x+\xi)-(y-\eta)(y+\eta)\right|\\
&\le |(x-\xi)(x+\xi)|+|(y-\eta)(y+\eta)|\\
&< r(2|x|+r)+r(2|y|+r)\\
&=2r(|x|+|y|+r)\\
&\le2r(|x|+|y|+1)\\
&<\delta \end{align}$$
so that also $0<\xi^2-\eta^2<1$. We conclude that the $r$-ball around $(x,y)$ is a subset of $A$.

Suppose $0>x^2-y^2$. With $\delta:=x^2-x^2>0$ and again $r=\min\{1,\frac\delta{2(|x|+|y|+1)}\}$, we find as above that $\left|(x^2-y^2)-(\xi^2-\eta^2)\right|<\delta$ and hence also $\xi^2-\eta^2<0$. We conclude that the $r$-ball around $(x,y)$ is disjoint from $A$. The same argument works for $x^2-y^2>1$ by using $\delta:=x^2-y^2-1$.

Suppose $0=x^2-y^2$. For every $r>0$, the $r$-ball around $(x,y)$ contains exterior points. Indeed, let $h=\min\{\frac r2,1\}$. Then if $y\ge 0$, we have
$$ x^2-(y+h)^2=x^2-y^2-2hy-h^2\le -h^2<0,$$
and if $y<0$, we have
$$ x^2-(y-h)^2=x^2-y^2+2hy-h^2\le -h^2<0.$$
The $r$-ball also contains interior points. Indeed, now let $h=\min\{\frac r2,1,\frac 1{2|x|+2}\}$. If $x\ge 0$, we have
$$ (x+h)^2-y^2=x^2-y^2+2hx+h^2=2hx+h^2>0,$$
but also
$$ (x+h)^2-y^2=2hx+h^2\le h(2x+1)<1.$$
Ans if $x<0$, we have
$$ (x-h)^2-y^2=x^2-y^2-2hx+h^2=-2hx+h^2>0,$$
but also
$$ (x-h)^2-y^2=2h|x|+h^2\le h(2|x|+1)<1.$$

Finally, suppose $x^2-y^2=1$. Then the same type of boring estimates shows that every $r$-ball around $(x,y)$ contais bothinterior and exterior points.

Comment: That is really a disguised way to not speak of $(x,y) \mapsto x^2-y^2$ continuity but proving that it is continuous! *Which by the way can't probably be avoided...*

Comment: Is my idea for proving the closure of $A$ correct?